# Why is my LogError function resetting GetLastError?

Tags: c++

I created a library that gets the last error as a string and then outputs that error to a file but for some reason my SetLogLocation and LogError function makes GetLastError() return 0. It should not return 0 though because in the test below I am forcing GetModuleHandle to fail. Why is GetLastError() returning 0?  Also, is handling errors such as fopen or GetModuleHandle failing in a library not recommended?

```
// test.exe
int main()
{
    if (!GetModuleHandleA("xxx"))
    {
        SetLogLocation("c:\\users\\admin\\desktop\\error.log");
        LogError("test");
    }

    // outputs 0
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    std::cout << dwError;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

// test.dll
EXPORT void SetLogLocation(std::string path)
{
    g_LogFile = std::ofstream(path, std::ios::app);
}

EXPORT void LogError(std::string errorText)
{
    if (!g_LogFile.good())
        return;

    DWORD dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    if (dwErrorCode == 0)
    {
        Log(errorText);
    }
    else
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << errorText << std::endl
           << "Last error: " << GetErrorAsString(dwErrorCode) << std::endl
           << "Error code: " << dwErrorCode;

        Log(ss.str());
    }
}

EXPORT std::string GetErrorAsString(DWORD dwErrorCode)
{
    LPSTR lpBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD dwSize = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, dwErrorCode, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&lpBuffer, 0, NULL);

    std::string errorMessage(lpBuffer, dwSize);
    if (errorMessage[errorMessage.length() - 1] == '\n')
        errorMessage.erase(errorMessage.length() - 1, 1);

    LocalFree(lpBuffer);
    return errorMessage;
}
```

Comment: It seems you got an error, you want to convert it into string then print string and get again error by `GetLastError`, but while converting into string you are calling `FormatMessageA` and `LocalFree` which also can fail and set error code. If they were executed fine, GetLastError returns 0.

Comment: Every system call may override the stored error. (The idea to have one global error state per process is old and probably not the best but can hardly be changed now.) You should call (and, maybe, temporarily store in case) the `GetLastError()` immediately after each resp. call.

Comment: So functions that succeed such as LocalFree or opening a filestream will reset GetLastError to 0. Therefore, when I call the above functions I will have to make sure I call LogError right away (as soon as the error happens) because calling other functions like SetLogLocation will cause the error to be lost. If I want to get the error twice I need to call GetLastError before LogError.

Answer (score 1):

A call to most windows functions will reset `GetLastError`, you need to store the value of `GetLastError` as soon as possible after your failing function then use that value rather than calling `GetLastError` again.

`SetLogLocation` will clear `GetLastError` as it is opening a file. `FormatMessageA` inside `LogError` will also clear `GetLastError`.

If you want your logging functions to not alter `GetLastError` you can always save and restore the value at the end of your functions:

```
struct LastError
{
  LastError()
  : value(getLastError())
  {
  }

  ~LastError()
  {
    SetLastError(value);
  }

  DWORD value;
};

EXPORT void SetLogLocation(std::string path)
{
    LastError lastError;
    g_LogFile = std::ofstream(path, std::ios::app);
}

EXPORT void LogError(std::string errorText)
{
    LastError lastError;
    if (!g_LogFile.good())
        return;

    if (lastError.value == 0)
    {
        Log(errorText);
    }
    else
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << errorText << std::endl
           << "Last error: " << GetErrorAsString(lastError.value) << std::endl
           << "Error code: " << lastError.value;

        Log(ss.str());
    }
}
```